# Notification by Email on Process termination

Tags: windows, vbscript, notifications, crash

We have a very critical process that needs to be monitored. If it crashes for some reason the admin needs immediate notification. We have tried different scenario's but none work for their own reasons:

1. VBScript `SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name LIKE '%IPRUN%'`
   This doesn't work because the process doesn't exit on crash it goes a WER   window. So when you hit close in WER window only then the process exits (i.e. disappears from the task manager) so until the process doesn't disappear this code is useless.
2. EventViewer: The application produces Start and Close events but does not for crashed events (for reasons understood) as application thread has exited abnormally, and might be its handled in an unusal way

Is there any other way of monitoring this?

Comment: Can you use the Start and Close events as "heartbeats"? Eg, `If lastStartEvent > Minutes(10) Then Email Admin`

Comment: No, because these events occur when a user interacts with the application. E.g. When I start the application, When I close the application. We need to monitor the crashing of an application

Comment: Use a monitoring system. That's exactly what they were invented for.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Sure Thanks. I wanted to achieve something on my own by learning things. I know there are a whole lot of monitoring tools out there free and commercial.

Comment: You said the process is critical. I do not recommend using things like that as a learning platform.